# Not able to use per BackgroundWorker filled model data with MVVM pattern

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, thread-safety, backgroundworker

I have WPF application with MVVM implementation and do successful fill model data (ObservableCollection) with BackgroundWorker.

By trying to show Dialog with this model data, I get error "*XamlParseException: Must create DependencySource on same Thread as the DependencyObject*".

How can I fix thread save implementation of MVVM-Pattern?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the DoWork method of BackgroundWorker before:

```
Facade.Instance.FillCache()
```

and after:

```
App.Current.Dispatcher.Invoke(new Action(() => Facade.Instance.FillCache()));
```

Thanks!